# Strip javascript from Drupal 8

Tags: 8

I want to strip all the javascript from a website.
Only have the libraries available when I need em on a page.

After a fresh install, with using bootstrap theme, I already have 50+ script tags including javascript files on the frontpage. https://www.pastery.net/hgxhsn

I know in d8 you can attach JS libraries to a render array, but it seems even when nothing is attached and no requirements are needed it blasts JS.

How could i strip and have only those attachments define requirements?

Comment: You have a Bootstrap theme and are logged in as admin. To remove most or all of the javascript install a standard theme and log out.

Comment: Indeed, with Stark set as default theme and logged out i only got html5shiv as js. But logged in I get a lot of js libraries that are still loaded. Is there a way to make em load only when needed?

Comment: This depends on how you configure the user role. For example if the user has no permission for "Access in-place editing", then quickedit.js is not loaded.